# Transpose cells until parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transpose all cells in column "Item" until it encounters depth 1. Looping for +10000 cells

```
Item Depth
A   1
B   2
C   2
D   3
E   4
F   5
G   1
H   2
I   2
J   1
K   2
```

and I need this result:

```
Item Depth                      
A   1   A   B   C   D   E   F
B   2                       
C   2                       
D   3                       
E   4                       
F   5                       
G   1   G   H   I           
H   2                       
I   2                       
J   1   J   K               
K   2
```

I think VBA would be more appropriate for this job but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you highlight A-K first, so select from A2 to A12.

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim outputCell As Range

For Each currentCell In Selection

    If currentCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 Then
        Set outputCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 2)
    Else
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(0, 1)
    End If

    outputCell.Value = currentCell.Value

Next currentCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Works Perfect, will now try to figure out how to do this with multiple colums.

Comment: Shout if you need a hand

Comment: Worked with two columns, I select both and changed `Set outputCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 3)` and voila, all that I need!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Item` is in A1, it is possible with a formula, if `1` is inserted in the first blank cell in ColumnB:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND($B2=1,COLUMN()<3+MATCH($B2,$B3:$B11000,0)),OFFSET(B2,COLUMN()-3,2-COLUMN()),""),"")
```

copied across and down to suit, until an entire column is blank.